# exporting sas data with special characters in column names to .CSV file

Tags: csv, sas, export-to-csv

Hello how do I export the data from sas, with special column names to CSV file.

for example see the column names:

PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE test2 AS SELECT 
        name as 'first. (name)'n,
        city as 'some. (city)'n

FROM test ;
QUIT;

I want the column names in csv as: 
column1: first. (name) 
column2: some. (city)

I can use proc step or data step to export based on your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`proc export` works fine as long as you have this:

```
options validvarname=any;
```